# Close popup by clicking outside it javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I used this tutorial to add popups to my webpage. Is there a way to make it so a popup closes when you click outside it/click on a different one.

I've tried adding an invisibleDiv as per this post [Close pop up div by clicking outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854464/close-pop-up-div-by-clicking-outside-of-it) but the popup is still only moving when the button itself is clicked.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
    /* Popup container - can be anything you want */
    .popup {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* The actual popup */
    .popup .popuptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 160px;
      background-color: #555;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 8px 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 125%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -80px;
    }
    
    /* Popup arrow */
    .popup .popuptext::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -5px;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    
    /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
    .popup .show {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
      animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }
    
    /* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
      from {opacity: 0;} 
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity:1 ;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center">
    <h2>Popup</h2>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element there are some non jquery answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a global click-handler that checks the clicked element's classList is one way to close the pop-up when clicking outside of it. Here is an example:

```js
const popups = [...document.getElementsByClassName('popup')];

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const popup = target.closest('.popup');
  const clickedOnClosedPopup = popup && !popup.classList.contains('show');
  
  popups.forEach(p => p.classList.remove('show'));
  
  if (clickedOnClosedPopup) popup.classList.add('show');  
});
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup.show .popuptext {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great but it doesn't work if I have two popups: 


var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  
function myFunction() {
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup') && popup.classList.contains('show')) myFunction();
});

var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  
function myFunction2() {
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup') && popup.classList.contains('show')) myFunction2();
});

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer to work for that case as well. Note that I'm now adding the show class to the container and not the popup.

Answer (score 3):

Add an onclick to the popup's container and stop event propagation on all internal elements you don't want to trigger the action.

```js
let popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

function toggle(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  popup.classList.toggle("hide");
}

function closePopup() {

  if (!popup.classList.contains("hide")) {
    popup.classList.toggle("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="closePopup()">
  <div class="popup hide" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"> </div>
  <Button onclick="toggle(event)">Toggle</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
<?php       
    echo '<div><a href="#" id="btnshow" onclick="showcontents();">Display Content</a></div>';
    echo '<div id="viewcontent"></div>';
 ?>
```

**Script**

> **Fill the generated content to the inside div**

```
function showcontents()
{
  var content = 'Add dynamic content';
  $('#viewcontent').html(content);
}
```

> **Empty the div content by clicking outside div**

```
$("body").click(function(e) 
{
  var contentlength = $("#viewcontent").text().length;      
  if(contentlength > 0 && e.target.id != 'btnshow'){
     $('#viewcontent').html("");
  }
}
```